# Name of $\log(-x)$ graph

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

I am currently writing an essay and am wondering if there/ what is the official name of the $\log(-x)$ graph. The searches that I have found seem to only give me that is inverse logarithmic, however, this seems to not be correct. Hopefully, someone could help me figure out what the official name of this graph is.

Thanks.

[image: Picture of Graph]

Comment: The attached graph is not the graph of $\log(-x),$ which is undefined when $x>0.$

Comment: I will say even more than @saulspatz : the graphical representation you show has nothing to see with a function of the form ln$(ax+b)$...

Comment: This could be the graph of $\log(8-x)$ but with a base of logarithm not $10$ or $e$. As for your question, I would just call $\log(-x)$ as the reflection of $\log x$ across the $y$ axis.

Comment: @JeanMarie How can you be sure?

Comment: Honestly, not sure 100%. But It is much too vertical in $x=7$ to be the graphical representation of $y=log_b(8-x)$ for any basis $b$. In any case, what is the relationship with $y=log(-x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I attached a picture with the graph shifted into quadrant 1 in order to simply have a clearer picture.

Comment: The shifted graph you attached seems to be $x=7-9^{y-2}$ (or $y=2+ \log_9(7-x)$), but I would need to see if the point $(-2,3)$ is on the graph. However, if the point $(7,0)$ **actually is** on the graph (rather than $(7-9^{-2},0)$), then $y$ isn't $2+\log_9(7-x)\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham Johri commented, $\log(-x)$ is just “the reflection of $\log x$ across the $y$ axis.” It doesn't have an special name; we translate, scalate and reflect functions in mathematics all the time. However, $\log(-x)$ is not an inverse logarithmic, since $\log(\log(-x)) \neq x$; the inverse of a logarithmic function is an exponential function (of the same base), actually.

As for the shifted graph you attached, it seems to be $x=7−9^{y−2}$ (or $y=2+\log_9(7−x)$), but I would need to see if the point $(−2,3)$ is on the graph. However, if the point $(7,0)$ **actually is** on the graph (rather than $(7−9^{−2},0)$), then $y$ isn't $2+\log_9(7−x)\ldots$